# Прикрепить файл html к свойствам bean в context

Tags: java, xml, spring, context, bean-validation

Настраиваю bean одной сущности в Context.xml
раньше у меня было

```
<bean id="name" class="path.name">
        <property name="from" value="mail"/>
        <property name="text">
            <value><![CDATA[

тут был очень большой html
            ]]></value>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

вот собственно я этот большой html вынес в ресурсы чтобы он не портил собой офомление контекста.
Можно ли как то привязать этот файл Template.html с полем `<value>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне кажется, что хорошим вариантом решения вашей задачи будет передача пути к файлу, и чтение html из этого файла в коде.

Context.xml

```
<bean id="name" class="path.name">
    <property name="from" value="mail"/>
    <property name="path" value="/templates/Template.html"/>
</bean>
```

Java class

```
String html = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path)));
```